# What is the difference between CPU Usage and CPU Utilization?

Tags: java, netbeans, visualvm

To evaluate my Java codes I want to use VisualVM, I noticed it showed me CPU Usage and when I go to search regarding it, I'm also shown CPU Utilization. Is there a definitive difference between the two ? I want to talk about CPU Usage in the context of real time systems but nothing specific comes out and rather both seem to be similar to each other?

Comment: found an answer here: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/vCenter-Server-Discussions/CPU-Utilization-vs-Usage/td-p/327157#:~:text=Utilization%20reflects%20the%20amount%20of,of%20power%20management%20or%20hyperthreading.

Comment: @skomisa As you wish, but I have mixed emotions about reputatian for good googeling :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Utilisation is of the physical CPU and Usage is of the logical CPU,
> this is based on CPU Hyperthreading.

I found this in the [VMware-community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66689902/what-is-the-difference-between-cpu-usage-and-cpu-utilization?noredirect=1#comment117909668_66689902)

Answer (score 1):

You are in a shared environment when using a VM and other instances besides your own, are competing for time on the same core. For example, you might be using only a part of the core time and the rest might be getting used by other instances. In this case, CPU usage will take into account both your usage as well as the usage of other instances when reporting. In other words, CPU usage is calculated as the percentage of your CPU usage as a function of the total.

CPU utilization takes into account only your metrics - the amount of time your CPU is busy or idle.